# what else is needed to prove that a mutivariable limit exists if the point is defined in the limit?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

**For the sake of simplicity Im asking the question using $f : \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^1$, but if anything relevant arises in $f : \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^1$, please do tell.**

Given some function $f : \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^1$, let's say I plug some point $P\in \mathbb{R}^2$ in the function and I find that $f(P)$ is defined and gives some value $L$.

What else do I need to prove that the limit at that point exists?
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to P}f(x,y)=L$$

Is my understanding that $f$  needs to be continuous close to $P$ but  does it need to be Smooth too? Is there anything else that could *ruin it*?

Sorry if it seems trivial but I have read contradicting answers around, stuff like "if you plug it in and it gives a value then the limit exists", this aswer seems to suggest that [just continuity will do it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3002981/is-it-sufficient-to-just-plug-in-numbers-to-prove-that-a-limit-exists-for-mult), but after some thought experiments I'm not convinced.

Thanks.

Comment: In theory, it's putting the cart before the horse by saying that continuity gives you the limit because the definition of continuity is that the limit exists and equals the value of the function at that point. But in practice, you can technically use your intuition for what's continuous and what isn't to preemptively guess which functions will have limits that definitely exist (aka the answer "falls down from the sky")  With those guesses, you can rigorously prove a limit via squeeze theorem or $\epsilon - \delta$, but if you "know" the function is continuous you can guess the result.

Comment: you are right, I was so confused by simplistic statements and I had not extrapolated the definition of continuity from single variable calculus yet.